# Flutter Listview issue adding items at the top

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a simple lisview with animated items. Everything is working fine, BUT when I tried to add the items at the top the behavior of the animated item is wrong

Here is my state class

```py
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<ItemAnimado> lista = [];

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
      lista.add(ItemAnimado(_counter.toString()));
      //lista.insert(0, ItemAnimado(_counter.toString()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder( itemCount: lista.length, itemBuilder: ( context, index,) {

        return lista[index];
      },),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my animatedItem

```py
    class _ItemAnimadoState extends State<ItemAnimado> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      AnimationController _controller;
      Animation<Offset> animation;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
        animation = Tween<Offset>(
                      begin: const Offset(1, 0),
                      end: Offset.zero,
                    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.bounceOut));

        _controller.forward();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SlideTransition(
                position: animation,
                //duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 9,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(widget.texto),
                  ),
                ),
              );
      }
    }
```

https://giphy.com/gifs/d5Yd3FZFNNKuTr5ku5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to make the code works as I wanted.

The State class is almost the same. BUT, now I have a globalKey for the AnimatedList.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      Provider.of<ItemProvider>(context).addItem(
          ItemAnimado(texto: 'New item'), 0);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _itemProvider = Provider.of<ItemProvider>(context);
    _itemProvider.providerKey(_listKey);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: AnimatedList(
        key: _listKey,
        initialItemCount: _itemProvider.listaItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
          return SlideTransition(
            //key: _myListKey,
            position: animation.drive(Tween<Offset>(
              begin: const Offset(1, 0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            )),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 9,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(_itemProvider.listaItems[index].texto),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But the most important part is in how I manage the data. I'm using a Provider 
I'm sending the Key to the Provider and in here I manage the insertItem inside the addItem function

```
class ItemProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  List<ItemAnimado> _listaItems = [
    ItemAnimado(texto: '1'),
    ItemAnimado(texto: '2'),
    ItemAnimado(texto: '3'),

  ];
  GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey;

  void providerKey(GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> key ){
    _listKey = key; 
  }

  List<ItemAnimado> get listaItems {
    return [..._listaItems];
  }

  addItem(ItemAnimado nuevo, int index){
    _listaItems.insert(0,nuevo);
    _listKey.currentState.insertItem(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Here is a Gif with the final result 
http://www.giphy.com/gifs/QybBE5E8kUUtxIbsnw

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you need to use Keys in your widgets. Here's a complete example:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<ItemAnimado> lista = [];

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
      lista.add(ItemAnimado(_counter.toString(), key: ValueKey(_counter)));
      //lista.insert(0, ItemAnimado(_counter.toString()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder( itemCount: lista.length, itemBuilder: ( context, index,) {

        return lista[index];
      },),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}

class ItemAnimado extends StatefulWidget {

  final String texto;

  ItemAnimado(this.texto, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _ItemAnimadoState createState() => _ItemAnimadoState();
}

class _ItemAnimadoState extends State<ItemAnimado> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Offset> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: const Offset(1, 0),
                  end: Offset.zero,
                ).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.bounceOut));

    _controller.forward();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: animation,
      //duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 9,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(widget.texto),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Notice where we added `key: ValueKey(_counter)` in the creation of your `ItemAnimado`. The key tells Flutter which widgets have already been created and which ones have been newly added.

For more on Keys, [see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc).

Comment: Hey, this is great, I did apply the changes, however if I try to add the items at the top using lista.insert(0, ItemAnimado(_counter.toString(), key: ValueKey(_counter)));
The behavior still wrong, look: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/Rhvj6UByCSEQoyNJE3